# Parse push: opening activity based on uri

Tags: android, android-activity, parse-platform, push

I am trying to open an activity depending on what the uri contained within the Parse push notification is. The documentation mentions that I have to override the "getActivity" method (https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#receiving/Android), however I am unsure as how to do so in my custom made onPushOpen method. How would I go about solving this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: If your push has no "uri" parameter, onPushOpen will invoke your application's launcher activity To customize this behavior, you can override getActivity in your ParsePushBroadcastReceiver subclass.

Comment: Yes, I know. My question was as how that is actually done in practice.
I have the following class 
`public class ParseReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver`
that deals with onPushReceive and onPushOpen. How do I override the getActivity method in my onPushOpen method?

Comment: method cannot be overriden inside method. you have to override the getActivity method in the ParseReceiver class. post this class here more better answer

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll try to work something out, although I find the documentation fairly sparse on information on how to do this. Would you happen to know of any examples/tutorials?

Comment: u already read it http://blog.parse.com/2014/09/30/android-push-gets-major-refresh/ ?